# PDO not accessible from included file in function

Tags: php, function, include, pdo

I have the following code that makes a PDO object, which is at the end of core.php:

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=xxx", 'xxx', 'xxx');
} catch (PDOException $exc) {
    header(HTTP_500_HEADER);
    die('Database connection failure');
}
```

In index.php, which is in a directory above it, it includes fine and I am able to access it. I am not accessing $dbh from a function.

However, when I try to access it from inside a function like this (this time it's a different file in a different dir):

```
require_once '../_/core.php';
var_dump($dbh);

$show_html = true;
$rm = $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

function login_check() {
    var_dump($dbh);
}
```

The first var dump shows it is a PDO object, but the second shows it's null.

Comment: $dbh is in the Global scope. Inside a function, all variables are local to the function (thus $dbh is empty). If you wanna use a var that's in the global scope inside a function, you have to make them global first, as shown in Jerzy's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access a global variable in a function you need to define it (here `$dbh`) as global inside the function (also see [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)):

```
function login_check() {
    global $dbh;
    var_dump($dbh);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is down to [scope](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php). Read up on the global keyword.

Answer (score 0):

```
function login_check() {
    global $dbh;        
    var_dump($dbh);
}
```